# Replacement for MathTime Pro

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I have a .tex source file which uses **MathTime Professional 2**. As MathTime Pro is not a free licensed font, I was wondering if it would be possible to change it to another similar font with a free license (like LPPL, GPL, Public Domain...). Is there any free replacement to MathTime Pro with the exact or at least similar font metrics? The objective is to change the font without altering the proportions and the distribution of the document.

I have found [this](http://miktex.org/packages/belleek), but it only works with the basic MathTime fonts. Is `newtxmath` the alternative am I looking for? I have not tested any of them yet.

Comment: I would replace Math Times Pro with `newtx`. By default, it uses a free clone of Times, `TeX Gyre Termes`, but you can optionally use `Libertine,Minion, Garamondx, Baskervaldx` or `Utopia`. Take a look at the doc for details.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `Times Roman` clone math font family that has the exact same font metrics as MathTime Professonal II. (There are very few pairs of fonts that have the exact same font metrics. One such example is `Arial`, which has the very same font metrics as `Helvetica`.) Are you aware of the fact that the "lite" subset of the complete MathTime Professional II package *is* free of charge? Do check if your document compiles correctly if the package's `lite` option is selected.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean free as in cost/beer or free as in freedom? 'As in free software' is ambiguous since software may be free in either, both or neither sense!

Comment: Free as is freedom. It is true that it is very ambiguous to say it like that. I am editing the question.

Comment: @cfr - I must confess to not understanding the "free as in freedom" attribute, at least not with regard to fonts. Does "free as in freedom" mean, for all intents and purposes, the same as "being in the public domain"?

Comment: @Mario - Your qualifier "ensuring [that the free replacement] will not affect the distribution of the text in the document" is quite ambiguous: MathTime Professional is a math-mode font, not a text-mode font. As such, MathTime Professiona doesn't come into play anyway in the text portions of a document. Please clarify your objective. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico. I have tried to clarify the question. The objective is to not change the document distribution of paragraphs and images because of the equations changing of size. It would be perfect to find a font with the same font metrics. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Mico It should respect the essential freedoms defined by the FSF. Public domain or any free software license, as defined by the FSF, would suffice. I don't want to be too strict on that because I am not an expert in licensing and maybe there is a license allowing me to redistribute the code under reasonable terms but not recognized by the FSF.

Comment: @Mico What Mario said ^^^. Or something close. A font may be free to use without being free in the freedom sense. You may not be allowed to modify it, or not allowed to convert it to another form, for example. Or you might not be allowed to redistribute it. Etc. Think of the fonts you can install using the `getnonfreefonts(-sys)` script. Those are free as in cost but not free as in freedom.

Comment: @Mico “Free as in freedom” for fonts, primarily means that anyone can create a new version or extension of the font. So, for example, TeX Gyre Termes Math and XITS Math are extensions of professionally-created Times-like fonts that add OpenType math support.